# Spark SQL to explode array of structure

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I have the below JSON structure which I am trying to convert to a structure with each element as column as shown below using Spark SQL. Explode(control) is not working. Can someone please suggest a way to do this?

Input:

```
{
"control" : [
    {
      "controlIndex": 0,
      "customerValue": 100.0,
      "guid": "abcd",
      "defaultValue": 50.0,
      "type": "discrete"
    },
    {
      "controlIndex": 1,
      "customerValue": 50.0,
      "guid": "pqrs",
      "defaultValue": 50.0,
      "type": "discrete"
    }
  ]
}
```

Desired output:

```
controlIndex customerValue guid defaultValult  type

0            100.0         abcd   50.0         discrete

1            50.0          pqrs   50.0         discrete
```

Comment: Can you add the code you tried?

Comment: I tried this - select explode(control) from myview It makes one column and puts each structure inside that

Answer (score 3):

Addition to Paul Leclercq's answer, here is what can work.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.explode   
df.select(explode($"control").as("control")).select("control.*")
```

Answer (score 1):

Explode will create a new row for each element in the given array or map column

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.explode   

df.select(
  explode($"control")
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Explode will not work here as its not a normal array column but an array of struct. You might want to try something like

`df.select(col("control.controlIndex"),  col("control.customerValue"), col ("control. guid"), col("control. defaultValue"), col(control. type))`