# Spark Python - Select from a struct and returning from a specific depth

Tags: python, apache-spark

I'm new to Spark and Python - working in a Jupyter notebook.

Say I have the following XML:

```
<metadata>
    <person>
        <personalName>
            <surname>The Batmaner</surname>
        </personalName>
        <personalName>
            <surname>Batman</surname>
        </personalName>
    </person>
</metadata>
```

I've loaded this into a DateFrame using:

`df = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml").options(rowTag='metadata').load(path)`

Now I can see the data in `df` I want to pull out the whole section from `<person>` if `surname==Batman`

Essentially, I'm confused about 2 bits:

- Searching when there is that `struct` or repeating block so in my case multiple `personalName`s
- How to return everything from the `<person>` level

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After what I'm seeing, your processable entity should be `metadata > person > personalName` since Superman and Batman are not the same heroes, right? If so, when you specified `metadata` as a `rowTag`, Spark took everything under `metadata` and transformed it into a row with the following schema:

```
root
 |-- person: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- personalName: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- surname: string (nullable = true)
```

When you change the rowTag into `personalName`, you will get the following schema:

```
root
 |-- surname: string (nullable = true)
```

If still, your expected schema should be located at `metadata`, you should operate on the row with [Apache Spark SQL array functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/index.html#array), for instance like this:

```
<metadata>
    <person>
        <personalName>
            <surname>Superman</surname>
        </personalName>
        <personalName>
            <surname>Batman</surname>
        </personalName>
    </person>
</metadata>
<metadata>
<person>
    <personalName>
        <surname>XX</surname>
    </personalName>
</person>
</metadata>
<metadata>
<person>
    <personalName>
        <surname>EEEE</surname>
    </personalName>
    <personalName>
        <surname>Batman</surname>
    </personalName>
    <personalName>
        <surname>XXXXX</surname>
    </personalName>
</person>
</metadata>
```

```
val df = sparkSession.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
  .option("rowTag", "metadata")
  .load("./test_xml.xml")

df.filter(functions.array_contains($"person.personalName.surname", "Batman")).show(true)
```

Which should return:

```
+-----------------------------+
|person                       |
+-----------------------------+
|[[[Superman], [Batman]]]     |
|[[[EEEE], [Batman], [XXXXX]]]|
+-----------------------------+
```

You can find a pretty good listing of Spark SQL array functions here: [Querying Spark SQL DataFrame with complex types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28332494/querying-spark-sql-dataframe-with-complex-types)

---

**Update**

> Searching when there is that struct or repeating block so in my case multiple personalNames

For that you can use Apache Spark higher order and array functions. If you search `spark higher order function`, you will find a lot of blog posts and documentation about them. Above I gave you an example about filtering arrays.

> How to return everything from the  level

It depends on your schema. With `rowTag=metadata`, Spark returns you a row composed of a single field being a structure called `person` composed only of an array `personalName`. If you added more fields inside, it will be still queryable:

```
<metadata>
    <person>
        <id>1</id>
        <age>30</age>
        <personalName>
            <surname>Superman</surname>
        </personalName>
        <personalName>
            <surname>Batman</surname>
        </personalName>
    </person>
</metadata>
<metadata>
    <person>
        <id>2</id>
        <age>40</age>
        <personalName>
            <surname>XX</surname>
        </personalName>
        <personalName>
            <surname>EEEEE</surname>
        </personalName>
    </person>
</metadata>
<metadata>
    <person>
        <id>3</id>
        <age>50</age>
        <personalName>
            <surname>EEEE</surname>
        </personalName>
        <personalName>
            <surname>Batman</surname>
        </personalName>
        <personalName>
            <surname>XXXXX</surname>
        </personalName>
    </person>
</metadata>
```

With:

```
df.filter("person.id > 0")
  .filter(functions.array_contains($"person.personalName.surname", "Batman"))
  .show(false)
```

The result will be:

```
+------------------------------------+
|person                              |
+------------------------------------+
|[30, 1, [[Superman], [Batman]]]     |
|[50, 3, [[EEEE], [Batman], [XXXXX]]]|
+------------------------------------+
```

Otherwise, if you moved the pointer to `person`, your schema will lose a level, so it will be easier to write queries:

```
df.printSchema()
df.filter("id > 0")
  .filter(functions.array_contains($"personalName.surname", "Batman"))
  .show(false)
```

For a schema and data like this:

```
root
 |-- age: long (nullable = true)
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- personalName: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- surname: string (nullable = true)

+---+---+---------------------------+
|age|id |personalName               |
+---+---+---------------------------+
|30 |1  |[[Superman], [Batman]]     |
|50 |3  |[[EEEE], [Batman], [XXXXX]]|
+---+---+---------------------------+
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I've updated my question - using superman wasn't clear. What I mean to show was say the the 2 names were actually different but refer to the same.

Comment: Thanks. I added an update. Still, I'm not sure to understand your questions correctly :/

Comment: Thanks - that helped. By the way, when working with a large XML file in the GBs. Is this this `.filter(functions.array_contains($"personalName.surname", "Batman"))` quite performant. I found it takes a little while - or is there an alternative.

Comment: Another approach would consist on "unflattening" the array with explode function and applying a simple filter operation on it. But it's an extra operation on the dataset so probably it won't change a lot. You can see an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46794062/spark-sql-to-explode-array-of-structure?rq=1 Eventually one thing that can help is the manual definition of the schema. You can check the `inferSchema` parameter https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml  schemas =>: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/sql-programming-guide.html#programmatically-specifying-the-schema